# Number of days between two dates doesn't produce right results

Tags: php, mysql

Having some issues with calculating number of days between two dates, I have already examined other threads related to this question and couldn't solve my problem.

I'm using this PHP code:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $now = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
            $to = strtotime($row["pickupdate"]);
            //$days = 0;
            $days = $to - $now;

            if ($days <= 5 && $days >= 0)
            {
                echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>...
```

In my database, I have four "pickupdate"s that are within the range of the if condition, but when I run the query and display the result, I only get two.

I get the same two outputs, which means, it only finds 0 days, but not 1 and 2 days, which I have setup in the database.

Dates in the database within the range:

- 2016-06-11
- 2016-06-09
- 2016-06-09
- 2016-06-12

So why isn't 11th and 12th of this month displayed when clearly they're within the range of the if statement?

I have changed the if statement to:

```
if ($days >= 0 && $days <= 100)
```

I still get the same exact two results,

Any help or direction would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You are subtracting a string from a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments you are subtracting strings. It won't work.

```
$days = (strtotime($to) - strtotime($now))/86400;
```

Comment: He has already converted the strings to timestamp before subtraction. Putting a timestamp through strtotime() would return false. What was missing was the division part only.

Comment: @user6439245 I think there was a quick edit of the question. If you edit within a few minutes the "edited" does not show up. Or I missread his code. But I remember the codepart beeing scrollable on mobiles the first time I read the question

Answer (score 1):

There are 84600 seconds in a day, in order to get result of difference in days, you need divide your result by 84600

Either 
Change

```
$days = $to - $now;
```

to

```
$days = ($to-$now)/86400;
```

Alternatively you can replace

```
 $now = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
 $to = strtotime($row["pickupdate"]);
 $days = $to - $now;
```

with

```
$days = (strtotime($row["pickupdate"]) - strtotime(date("Y-m-d")))/86400;
```